# Using Android Car API with the Android Automotive OS emulator: PERMISSION_CONTROL_CAR_CLIMATE cannot be granted

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, automotive

I've been playing recently with the Android Car API using the available Android Automotive OS AVD images (Polestar 2 and Automotive). The AVD UI reveals some controls for `HVAC` as well (on the "Vhal properties" tab), but so far I wasn't able to access them because the system denies the `PERMISSION_CONTROL_CAR_CLIMATE` request. The other permissions like `PERMISSION_SPEED`, `PERMISSION_POWERTRAIN` and `PERMISSION_ENERGY` have been granted and I could access the related sensor data etc. (mostly on the "Car sensor data" tab of the machine UI).

Q: Has anybody succeeded in accessing the `HVAC` properties on the aforementioned AVDs through the Car API?

Comment: Does work the feature via HVAC application?

Comment: PERMISSION_CONTROL_CAR_CLIMATE is not referenced in `developer API`. Also, IntelliSense in Android Studio 4.0 does not find it. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/Car

However, AOSP does show some references in PropertyHalServiceIds.java. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Car/+/master/service/src/com/android/car/hal/PropertyHalServiceIds.java . May be the said permission is removed?

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to e.g. `android.car.permission.CAR_SPEED`, the `android.car.permission.CONTROL_CAR_CLIMATE` is defined in the Android sources with `android:protectionLevel="signature|privileged"` attribute, which means that no ordinary apps can access it.